# Upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I am looking at upgrading MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0 (all in AWS).

I have the added benefit of a QA environment to work with, which is the obvious starting point.

I ran through their article here: [Upgrading the major version of an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.MajorVersionUpgrade.html#AuroraMySQL.Updates.MajorVersionUpgrade.2to3)

Most of the article makes sense to me, but I have some questions related to the actual upgrade from 5.7 to 8.0.

Reading about the [MySQL Utility Checker](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-upgrade.html) , it does not check things like stored procedures, views and functions. How do I verify that existing stored procedures / views / functions are compatible with MySQL 8.0? Would the best way be to make a MySQL 8.0 sandbox, then build a replica dataset, then bring each procedure over?

There is definitely a comprehensive list of things to check that AWS provides. It is a general list of incompatibilities between the two versions. From my understanding this information is not caught by the utility checker, but I could be wrong.

What would be the best way to programmatically check say, all tables for a zero date time. To my knowledge they don't exist but the peace of mind will be very nice before fighting with the QA environment, then eventually production.

Comment: are you running mysql in ec2 or rds?

Comment: There is a setting to allow zero datetime.  That might be a simpler way to do the upgrade.  Then create the queries from I_S to check each column for "zero".  Is that what you are asking for?